# How to catch `IterableElementError.noElement` in Dart?

Tags: dart, exception

I can catch StateError and check for the message string but that looks ugly

```
abstract class State {}

class FoundState implements State {
  final int count;
  FoundState(this.count);
}

class NotFoundState implements State {
}

foo() {
  final Numlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  try {
    final found = Numlist.firstWhere((x) => x == 1234);
    return FoundState(found);
  } on StateError catch (ex) {
    if (ex.message == 'No element') { // Why string? an enum would have been better
      return NotFoundState();
    }
  }
}

main() {
  final x = foo();
  print(x);
}
```

I think about comparing with `IterableElementError.noElement` but it is in an internal folder.

Comment: Did you find any better solution?

Comment: @АлександрСавин I did use the `orElse` optional argument, that seems to be the 'dart way'.